# How to detect who is creating memory consumption in .NET app?

Tags: .net, memory-management

My Windows service is eating a lot of private data (yellow in VMMap)

I have a Visual Studio with Debugger. How can I find out who is consuming so much memory?

I think it must be unmananged C++ new operators.

Is it possible to detect without installing commercial third party memory profilers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [WinDbg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WinDbg) ([download](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463009)) with the [SOS.dll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb190764.aspx) extension to look at memory dumps of your application.

Comment: @captain: WinDbg is primarily for unmanaged code, SOS.dll is just an extension (amongst many) that also allows managed code.